# How to differentiate between display value and id value using the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin with remote data source?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search box in my application that uses the jQuery UI Autocomplete plugin to display a list of users in the system based on last name, from a remote data source.

When a user is clicked from the autocomplete list, I'd like the browser to redirect to that user's individual page (based on a GET parameter).  However, the GET parameter for the user page is the user "id", different from the display values "last_name, first_name".

How do I push the user "id" to the GET parameter while still displaying the first and last names values in the dropdown?

I have seen similar questions asked on here, but none while using a remote data source.

Any help you can provide, would be amazing!

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( ".user_autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
            source: "../../db/users.php",
            minLength: 0,
            focus: function (event, ui) {
                this.value = ui.item.value;
            },          
    }).bind( "autocompleteselect", function(event, ui) {
        window.location.href = "/users/index.php?id=" + this.value;
    });

});
```

**Remote Data Source (users.php)**

```
<?php

$return_arr = array();

if(isset($_GET['term'])) {
    $mysearchString = $_GET['term'];
}

$sth = $dbh->query("SELECT id, first_name, last_name FROM users
                    WHERE last_name LIKE '$mysearchString%'
                    ORDER BY last_name");

while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 

    $row_array = $row['last_name'].', '.$row['first_name'];

    array_push($return_arr,$row_array); 

}

echo json_encode($return_arr);

?>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the other examples you've seen? The data source shouldn't matter it since the plugin normalizes them all to the same interface.

Comment: Two issues.  I am not sure how to format the array in my remote data source to include both the display values and id values.  Also, I am not sure how to pass both of those values into the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an ID that is different from the (display) VALUE, you must return a JSON encoded array of objects like this:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "value":"Doe, John"
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "value":"Smith, Mary"
   }
]
```

You can then use `ui.item.id` to retrieve the selected ID.

NOTE: You can also provide a "label" property that is different from the "value" property. Here's the information from the documentation:

> The local data can be a simple Array of Strings, or it contains
>   Objects for each item in the array, with either a label or value
>   property or both. The *label* property is displayed in the suggestion
>   menu. The *value* will be inserted into the input element after the user
>   selected something from the menu. If just one property is specified,
>   it will be used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties,
>   the value will also be used as the label.

EDIT:

I'm not a PHP guy, but I imagine the code to create the JSON array would be something like this:

```
<?php
$return_arr = array();

    ... snip ...

while ($row = $sth->fetch ()) { 
    $row_array = array(
        "id" => $row['id'], 
        "value" => $row['last_name'].', '.$row['first_name']
    );
    array_push($return_arr, $row_array); 
}
echo json_encode($return_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks; however, how do I create this array with my remote data source code above and then pass it into the plugin?